# Obtaining the changed element of jquery on function when using [ selector ] attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery `on` to detect a change event of elements within a form. I am narrowing my selection using the selector attribute of the function as follows :

```
$("#myFormId,#myFormId2").on("change", ":input.classA, :input.classB, textarea" ,function()
{
   $(this).attr("id");
});
```

**Update - To elaborate the question**

How to get once any of the input fields changed within any of the 2 forms :

1. The changed element id *(I bet this could be done by setting the event returned object as stated in the comments `function(eventObj)`)*.
2. The form id of the changed element from the event itself without
       propagating upward in the DOM tree.

Comment: The first argument to the callback ought to be the element you're looking for: `function(eventObject) { ... }`, cf. [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: it does return the changed element's id

Comment: This works for me , Checkout this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/g83o2hrr/

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue ([see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qh6xd11q/)). Can you make your own [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to show the issue?

Comment: Also, "... the this keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated events this is an element matching selector. (Note that this may not be equal to event.target if the event has bubbled from a descendant element.)"

Comment: I am getting a different result within my environment, this seems weird. With what you are stating If I have multiple selection $("#myFormId, #myFormId2"), how to get the form ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this wrapped up at last :

In my environment, we are using jquery 1.6.4 which did not support jQuery `on` method. The `on` method was added as a customization but it still acted the same as `live` without delegate event binding even when using selectors.

That's why in the first place I was getting the form Id when using `$(this).attr("id");`.

As an answer to number 2 in the question, since we are using delegate event binding mode of the `on` method (in 1.7+ version), `$(this)` will always return the first target, i.e the element (form field) that directly has change `event.target`.

To obtain the main selector i.e `FormId`, we shall use `$(event.delegateTarget)` to get the main selector as the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g83o2hrr/1/) illustrates.